# Use of preposition on or for

Tags: prepositions

In the following sentence which preposition is suitable:

> The contest was set on/for the first of September >

In this situation the contest is being planned in advance.two parties are arranging it.
I have searched Internet but cannot find any help.

Comment: "The contest was set **for** the 1st of September" means the contest will be held on the 1st of September. "The contest was set **on** the 1st of September" tells us, "On the 1st of September the date for the contest was decided/agreed/chosen", but it doesn't tell us _when_ the contest will be held!

Comment: Agree about **for**. The version with **on** just sounds confusing. I don't know what it means for a concert to be "set," so I don't know what it means for a concert to be set on a certain date. I might actually just assume that the person who said "on" really meant "for."